# TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method when running program

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I'm having a typeError issue :

```
def compare(datafile,logfile,index_data,index_log,index_temp):
    datafile_csv = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter = ',',quotechar = '"')
    logfile_csv = csv.reader(logfile,delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
    row_data = []
    row_log = []
    row_data = datafile_csv.__next__()
    row_log = logfile_csv.__next__()
    logfile_len = sum (1 for lines in logfile_csv)
------>>>>#this is the part of code that is giving me an issue
    **out_write = csv.writer('resultfile',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)**
    #need to think about it
    while index_data != logfile_len:
            if row_data[index_data:] == row_log [index_log:]:
                    out_writer.writerow(row_log)
                    index_data += 1
                    index_log += 1
                    index_temp = index_log
            else :
                    while row_data [index_data:] != row_log [index_temp:]:
                            index_temp += 1
                            if row_data[index_data:] == row_log [index_log:]:
                                    out_writer.writerow(row_log)
                    index_temp = index_log
    gui.msgbox('This is the name of the newly generated log file :', out_writer)
```

I was reading many example and it seems that the syntax is correct.

What is the mistake i am making ?

thanks and regards

Danilo

Comment: `csv.writer` takes a file, not a file name.

Comment: You need an object that implements the `write` method, and string `openfile` obviously does not. Consider using `open(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('resultfile','w') as csvfile:
    out_write = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, it did work ! now i am having another issue but it is related to the structure of the program (i overhauled it), i posted a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671719/python-writing-program-to-iterate-a-csv-file-to-match-field-and-save-the-result , let me know if you can see what i am doing wrong...i think i am messing up the usage of the csv library.